# How to find in a string a commun name in two columns, different tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Im building a program in c# that consist in import two differents excel files into tables in data base, similar to this:

First table[Details]:

```
 Description                                Cost 
 Aeroport ticket by John                    200
 Emily Ticket to cinema                     200
 Aeroport ticket by Anna to the first class 500
```

Second Table[ClientInform]:

```
CostumerName Cost
John         200
Emily        200
Anna         500
```

Result table:

```
Description                               ClientName    Cost
Aeroport ticket by John                      John        200
Emily Ticket to cinema                       Emily       200
Aeroport ticket by Anna to the first class   Anna        500
```

I have to display this on a gridview but if I have the right query I think I can do it in asp.net fairly easy.. I just don't know How to Seach in a string that can be random lenght, I was thinking in something similar to this:

```
select * from Details
full join ClientInform
on ClientInform.CostumerName= Details.Description
where Details.Description Like '%' +ClientInform.CostumerName+  '%'
```

something that Searche's similiar strings in both columns

ps: the code in sql is just a demonstration

Comment: Have you tried the SQL you've written? If you did, why didn't it work? If you haven't, why not? You should try it.

Comment: @Larnu I tried it in SQL, but nothing happens

Comment: "nothing happens"? You don't even (an empty) get a dataset? Then you didn't run the SQL.

Comment: Try add to the SQL a USE DATABASE.  The default database may not be the correct one.  I usually in SQL start with SELECT * on bot tables to make sure I have data.

Comment: @Larnu Im a hundred porcent sure, That I had the excel files in database ofc... My bad that you did not understand what I meant... What I mean is that just shows me the headers but no records at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT d.Description, c.CustomerName, c.Cost 
FROM Details d
INNER JOIN ClientInform c on d.Description Like '%' +c.CostumerName+  '%' AND c.COst = d.cost
```

Note : `Like` used on joining condition is sure kill the query performance.